# Chrome cancels CORS XHR when redirected

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, redirect, cors, http-response-codes

I'm having a mysterious issue where Chrome cancels cross-origin AJAX requests when they encounter a HTTP redirect. In the Network tab, it appears as "(canceled)" and the response headers or body are not available.

Here's the flow:

1. Load page on http://
2. POST request to login endpoint on https://
3. 303 response
4. Request canceled.

Here's the JS (from `ajaxtest.html`):

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open('POST', 'https://dev.example.com/appName-rest/login', true);
r.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
r.send(JSON.stringify({"username":"myusername","password":"myrealpassword"}));
r.send();
```

Chrome's net internals shows that the server responded with these headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Date: Thu, 05 Sep 2013 17:54:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://dev.example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Location: https://dev.example.com/appName-rest/j_spring_cas_security_check?ticket=xxxx.example.com
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 52
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

And it says: URL_REQUEST_BLOCKED_ON_DELEGATE

Does anyone know why this is failing?

Comment: Are you using WebService?

Comment: Not sure.. I think so. But the code is just plain javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you are trying to do [Cross-Origin Request with Preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), because you setup 'Content-Type': 'application/json'. Preflighted requests with redirects are rejected by [CORS specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0).

Answer (score 0):

You are sending twice this method : r.send();

Please, try the following

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "YOUR_URL", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) { // if complete and success
            return xhr.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhr.withCredentials = true; // OPTIONAL : I don't know if you need it for CORS Requests
    xhr.send("username=YOUR_USERNAME&password=YOUR_PASSWORD");
```